# How do I change the build directory in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

Xcode 4 is building my project in

> /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME-ctikyzraibsmwfhfwpjgmszxjlnh/Build/Intermediates/PROJECT_NAME-.build/

instead of

> PROJECT_ROOT/build

How do I set the build dir. in Xcode 4?

In build settings, all "Build Product Path" keys are set to "build".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to XCode -> Preferences (or Cmd-,), then switch to "Locations" tab.  There you can specify where to put the compiled apps:

[image]